# Figaro Gem on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, secret-key

I'm struggling to set figaro up on my rails 4 app.

I have application.yml:

```
GMAIL_USERNAME_CFR: aaa@gmail.com
GMAIL_PW_PROD_CFR: bbb

GMAIL_USERNAME_PROD_WELCOME: ccc@gmail.com
GMAIL_PW_PROD_WELCOME: ddd
```

I have a production.rb file:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'gmail.com',
    user_name:            Figaro.env.GMAIL_USERNAME_CFR,
    password:             Figaro.env.GMAIL_PW_PROD_CFR,
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

In my user.rb I have 2 mailers set up. When I don't use figaro and just put the username and password directly in the production.rb file - these mailers work.  Using Figaro, I get an authentication error.

My user.rb methods are:

```
 def send_admin_mail
         puts "the value is:" + Figaro.env.GMAIL_USERNAME_CFR.to_s
         AdminMailer.new_user_waiting_for_approval(self).deliver
       end

       def send_user_welcome_mail

         AdminMailer.new_user_waiting_for_access(self).deliver
       end
```

You can see that I tried to figure out the problem with the puts line in the first method above. The log puts 'the value is' and then does not put the username as a string.

My mailers are:

```
def new_user_waiting_for_approval(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: "aaa@gmail.com", from: Figaro.env.GMAIL_USERNAME_CFR, 
    subject: "Registration Request #{user.first_name} #{user.last_name} <#{user.email}>")
  end

  def new_user_waiting_for_access(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: user.email, from: "ccc@gmail.com", subject: "Welcome, #{user.first_name}")
  end
```

You can see above that I have tried to use figaro in the first mailer and the email address in the second email. Neither option works. I have also tried ENV[] instead of Figaro.env before the username and password.

My console shows the details correctly when I convert them to strings - except they are shown between "". I assume that's of no significance.

Can anyone see what I need to do to fix my figaro setup?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Ok, my problem was I didn't load my environment variables from my `application.yml` to Heroku. Because the file is listed in `.gitignore`, it won't be commited to GitHub.

To load the environment variables to Heroku, do `figaro heroku:set -e production`. As it's explained [here](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro#deployment).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `Figaro.env` for it to read your **application.yml** file. Just grab the environment variables using standard rails.

For example, change:

```
Figaro.env.GMAIL_USERNAME_CFR
```

To:

```
ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME_CFR']
```

Change all instances of `Figaro.env` to this format.

Also, make the variables in your application.yml file set to strings.

```
GMAIL_USERNAME_CFR: "aaa@gmail.com"
GMAIL_PW_PROD_CFR: "bbb"

GMAIL_USERNAME_PROD_WELCOME: "ccc@gmail.com"
GMAIL_PW_PROD_WELCOME: "ddd"
```

Comment: Hi Miler, I'm afraid that didn't work. I still get an authentication error on the admin_mailer call. I don't get that error when I put the password and username directly into production.rb. It's driving me crazy. Thanks anyway for trying to help.